# Do mysql/mariadb has a limit on multicolumn index key size when a column is foreign key?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, foreign-keys, limit, database-indexes

Sorry, I'm not sure in the problem source and terminology, so the situation. I'm trying to execute

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

and then

```
CREATE TABLE `B` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `n` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `b` (`a_id`,`n`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `A` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

it runs OK, but when I instead try

```
CREATE TABLE `B` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `n` TEXT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `b` (`a_id`,`n`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `A` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

it fails, saying

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `DBNAME`.`B` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Same for `n VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL`, but `VARCHAR(767)` and less works fine. This is not index limit, since without foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE `B` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `n` TEXT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `b` (`a_id`,`n`)
);
```

it works fine. So what's the problem? I'm using MariaDB 10.4.17. Could I be sure that `VARCHAR(767)` and less would works fine on other machines/versions/mysql?

Comment: The problem is not FOREIGN KEY but UNIQUE index ```(`a_id`,`n`)```. You **must** specify indexed prefix length. Try ```(`a_id`,`n`(2048))``` - it works, try the same in MySQL - you will see "BLOB/TEXT column 'n' used in key specification without a key length".

Comment: @Akina, but it fails if and only if foreign key is used altogether with index...

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=3027ccf6bbec0c8562ab9120e0bc76fb